# Are There Any Good ASP.NET Stock Photo Apps?

Tags: asp.net, photos

I'm looking at collating mine and a few friends photos on our own stock photo site.. To save me some time I was wondering if anyone knew of a good stock photo app built in ASP.NET??

I have googled and not come up with much.. Looking for the ability for people to be able to buy from the site and the images watermarked so people can't steal them :)

Comment: do you just mean a photo gallery app built on .net?  Or like a store fornt used to sell photos?

Comment: An application I could use to sell photos - So a cross between a photo gallery and store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gallery Source Pro](http://www.galleryserverpro.com/) is an open source app that might be worth looking into.  I played around with the compiled version briefly, but I had major issues using the open source code application on a 64-bit top-bottom machine and gave up.  It does seem fairly flexible and I believe it can watermark images.

Comment: Thanks that was the only one I found... I'll download it and have a look

Answer (score 0):

[Phanfare](http://www.phanfare.com/home.aspx) is built in .NET, but they are a commercial outfit. There is [a public API](http://help.phanfare.com/index.php/API) available, so you may get some joy....